# Mule 'jersey:resources' Element: binding is not allowed to be child of element component

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I see following error in Anypoint studio,  while working with 'jersey:resources' component of Mule as per Mule Documentation.

I understand  this types of errors are due to not defining the schema. But here in this case, though schema defined, still points out the error  as **"not allowed to be child of element component"**.

[image]

Can any one help me in fixing this.?

**Anypoint Studio Details:**

Anypoint Studio January 2015 Release
Version: 5.0.2
Build Id: 201502251307

thanks

--Mohammad Rafiq.

Comment: Does it work despite the reported schema errors? Studio sometimes reports bogus schema errors: Mule has the final word when you try to start...

Comment: No it is not. instead i see an exception as : Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'binding' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint}' is expected..

Comment: Cool, the error is clear enough: you're missing an endpoint element inside the binding element.

Comment: I have defined schema as 
xmlns:abstract-outbound-endpoint="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
but still the same both compilation and runtime error(s).

Answer (score 0):

The `binding` element is [defined](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/modules/spring-config/src/main/resources/META-INF/mule.xsd#L3087-L3105) as:

```
<xsd:complexType name="pojoBindingType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="abstract-outbound-endpoint" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="interface" use="required" type="substitutableClass">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The interface to be injected. A proxy will be created that implements this interface by calling out to the endpoint.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="method" use="optional">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The method on the interface that should be used. This can be omitted if the interface has a single method.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
```

But you are trying to put a `flow-ref` element in it. This can't work. Add a `vm:inbound-endpoint` in the `TransformationFlow` and replace the `flow-ref` with a `vm:outbound-endpoint` connected to the `vm:inbound-endpoint`.

Reference material: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Component+Bindings

Comment: Hi, David! But the snippet from the question is actually coming from the official doc(https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/jersey-module-reference). In my case, I want to use bindings with new http:listener and I thought extracting http:listener into a separate flow and reference it with flow-ref would work. However, it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is http:request

Comment: Docs can be outdated, the proof is in the pudding :) And you probably want to open a new question for your particular problem.